# Get the value of ngModel without performing any action [Ionic]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When a user clicks on a button on the same HTML page, I want to send the value of `<ion-text>` to a TypeScript file. However, it did not work.

```
  <ion-text [(ngModel)]='xy' ngDefaultControl  >'variables from a global provider' </ion-text>
  <ion-button (click)="callFun()">Save</ion-button>
```

TypeScript file:

```
    xy:string;
    ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.xy);
    }   
    callFun(){
 console.log(this.xy);
    }
```

In the console, it returns `undefined`. How can I obtain it? I'm unable to use the `(ionChange)` function with `ion-text`.

Comment: ion-text is not two-way binding -you can not change by user action-. If you use `[NgModel]` you need give value to the variable. Are you asking about ion-input?

Comment: no i'm asking about ion-text, because I have a global variable, and I have added it in ion-text like this <ion-text> {{global.x}}</ion-text>

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't want to use data-binding? Sounds like the most simple solution to your problem.

Comment: I have a global provider with numerous variables, and on the home page, I assign values to the global variables. When an user clicks a button on the home page, they are redirected to a modal. I display the golbal variables in ion-text in the html of the modal; now I need to read the value of ion-text in the typescript file of this modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm from Angular, but to work [ngModel] the ion-text component should to have a property "value",

I imagine you can use

```
   <ion-text #myText>{{global.x}}</ion-text>`

   <ion-button (click)="callFun(myText)">Save</ion-button>

   callFun(text:any){
     console.log(text.innerHTML);
    }
```

But, apologies, I don't know about Ionic :(